# Convert date to number data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am trying to convert date to number like below, not sure which function works better.

Database used is SQL Server.

Table details

```
create table test 
(
    id varchar(255),
    call_date varchar(255)
);

insert into test('26203', '14-Aug-2020');
```

I need output as 4405726203 -- its concatenation of date (`14-Aug-2014`) + id (`26203`)

Comment: Go to the SQL Server documentation and check out the functions available.

Comment: And where does 44057 come from?

Comment: I tried to use CAST(CONVERT(datetime,call_date) as bigint) - it returns 44055, when concatenation with id, it sums up the values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff 44057 should be the numeric or other conversion of date.

Comment: Convert them to strings before concating them.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

SQL Server allows you to convert a `datetime` to a float.  That would be:

```
select cast(dte as float)
from (values (convert(datetime, '14-Aug-2020'))) v(dte)
```

However, the corresponding floating point value is 44055 (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d142a64db0872e7572eb4fbd6d5d5fe7).  It is a bit of mystery what your intention is.

You could subtract 2, but that seems arbitrary.  You could calculate the number of days since 1899-12-30.  But that also seems arbitrary.

In any case, once you figure out how to convert the date to the number you want, just use `concat()` to combine the values.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution:

```
convert(varchar,CAST(CONVERT(datetime,call_date) as bigint)) + id
```

Comment: Always specify length for datatypes.It can lead to issues, difficult to troubleshoot. For VARCHAR, It takes default length as 30 for CAST, CONVERT. but, we should not depend on database to define length. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, a SQL Server `DateTime` is a tuple of 2 32-bit integers:

- The first integer is a count of days since since the epoch, which for SQL Server is `1 January 1900`
- The second integer is a count of milliseconds since start of day (`00:00:00.000`). Except that the count ticks up in 3- or 4-milliscond increments. Microsoft only knows why that decision was made.

You can get the count of days since the epoch with

```
convert( int, convert( date, t.call_date ) )
```

[wrap that in `convert(varchar, ... )` to turn it into a string]

Looks like your `id` is already a `varchar`, so you can say:

```
select compound_key = convert(varchar,
                        convert(int,
                          convert(date,
                            call_date
                          )
                        )
                      )
                    + t.id
from test t
```

I would suggest padding both fields with leading zeros to a fixed length so as to avoid possible collisions (assuming you're trying to generate a key here). Signed 32-bit integer overflows a 2.1 billion-ish, so 9 digits for each field is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
select concat(datediff(d, 0, cast(call_date as date)), id)
from 
  (values ('26203','14-Aug-2020')) v(id, call_date);
```

Results

```
4405526203
```